# Trouble with bidirectional references using Option<Rc<RefCell<T>>>

Tags: rust

I am building a NES emulator to learn Rust. I have difficulty organizing components.

My emulator uses the structure Bus to communicate with CPU and PPU. CPU and PPU also need to communicate with bus.

I figured that it is a good idea to create a shared pointer for Bus so that PPU and CPU have the same pointer reference to a bus. This is what I tried: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=937648053ac3f53d5ef69ba26fc2df4d). Unfortunately it didn't work.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:33:9
   |
32 |     fn bus(&mut self) -> &mut Bus {
   |                          -------- expected `&mut Bus` because of return type
33 |         self.bus_helper().borrow_mut()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         expected `&mut Bus`, found struct `RefMut`
   |         help: consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut self.bus_helper().borrow_mut()`
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut Bus`
                         found struct `RefMut<'_, Bus>`
```

How to get my code to compile? Also, I wonder whether it is the best way to create bidirectional references? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: If you're a beginner in Rust, I really recommend you to change your design to not use unsafe. One way might be to [use `Arc::new_cyclic`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=21a300c1b1bf1faa5244ccedc4793a90). Alternatively if your Bus, CPU, and PPU are singletons that live for the entirety of your application anyway, you could use [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) and make them global variables.

Comment: @Caesar Thanks, the Arcs seems promising but unfortunately I want to make bus a mutable object. Is there any way to make mutable arcs?

Comment: Sure. But you'll have to [sprinkle](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59686e1a01640f99374b65604d65e5e5) your code with `.borrow_mut()` and friends. (And beware that `RefCell` or not, you can still only have one mutable reference.) Maybe an entirely different design approach is in order. You're only doing this separation into three structs for separation/namespacing reasons, right? There are better ways, having multiple `impl` blocks, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`borrow_mut()` returns a [`RefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html), which is a wrapper that maintains the borrow count of the cell so that the cell can panic if Rust's aliasing rules are violated at runtime (e.g. if a mutable reference and any other reference try to exist at the same time).

You can fix this by changing the return type to `RefMut<'_, Bus>`.

Alternatively, to make the `RefCell` implementation detail hidden from the caller, you can instead return `impl DerefMut<Target=Bus> + '_` which says "this method returns something that can deref as a mutable `Bus` and which captures the lifetime of `self`."

> Also, I wonder whether it is the best way to create bidirectional references?

Generally for bidirectional references, you want all of the references away from the "primary value" (e.g. the root of a tree) to be `Rc` and references in the other direction to be [`Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html). This allows you to drop the primary value and have the whole network of structures be automatically destroyed.  If you have two values with `Rc`s to each other then you have a reference cycle that must be explicitly broken to avoid a memory leak when you release your "top-level" reference to the network of structures.

However, if you find yourself wanting bidirectional references in this kind of case where you have a *fixed* set of values that want to refer to each other, you likely want a different pattern altogether.  Based on your playground link, the CPU and PPU have strong shared ownership of the bus, and the bus has weak ownership back to the CPU and PPU.  (In your model, you should express that with `Weak` and not raw pointers.)

What this hints at is that a single entity should own all of the components, and that entity should be responsible for their communication.  There's a few ways you could model this.

- A `System` value owns all of the components, and this value would provide a communication mechanism.  This would replace `Bus`.  The circular reference can be avoided by requiring a reference to `System` be given to the component values any time they need to do anything.
- Channels could be used for communication between components, though this makes synchronous messaging between components trickier.
- If the performance implications of channels are prohibitive and the desired API can't work by passing references to `System` around with every call, you could have references from the components back to `System` *if* you pin `System` so that it can't move, and therefore the references can't be invalidated.  This is a bit of an advanced topic; you may want to [read the relevant documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#example-self-referential-struct).