# Mediator design pattern in Rust

Tags: rust, mediator

Please suggest how to implement such a design. I understand that `mediator` needs to be passed as a reference. But I can't figure out the lifetime parameter.

```
//Colleague
struct Switcher {
    state: bool,
    mediator: SyncMediator
}
impl Switcher {
    fn sync(self) {
        self.mediator.sync(self.state);
    }

    fn get_state(&self) -> bool {
        return self.state;
    }

    fn set_state(&mut self, value: bool) {
        self.state = value;
    }
}

//ConcreteMediator
struct SyncMediator {
    switchers: Vec<Switcher> 
}
impl SyncMediator {
    fn sync(mut self, state: bool) {
        for i in 0..self.switchers.len()  {
            self.switchers[i].set_state(state);
        }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, switcher: Switcher) {
        self.switchers.push(switcher);
    }   
}

fn main() {
    //Client
    let mediator = SyncMediator {
        switchers: vec![] };
    let mut switcher1 = Switcher {
        mediator: mediator, state: false };
    let switcher2 = Switcher {
        mediator: mediator, state: false };
    let switcher3 = Switcher {
        mediator: mediator, state: false };

    switcher1.set_state(true);
    let mut state2 = switcher2.get_state();
    //state2 is false
    let mut state3 = switcher3.get_state();
    //state3 is false
    println!("state2 is {state2}");
    println!("state2 is {state3}");

    switcher1.sync();
    state2 = switcher2.get_state();
    //state2 is true
    state3 = switcher3.get_state();
    //state3 is true        
    println!("state2 is {state2}");
    println!("state2 is {state3}");
}
```

Comment: Related: [Question with a similar design problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73001069/trouble-with-bidirectional-references-using-optionrcrefcellt#comment128936160_73001069) (Your mediator is their bus.) And a general hint: design patterns that work well in other programming languages often don't in Rust.

Comment: Having `Switcher` own a `Weak<SyncMediator>` corresponding to an `Rc<SyncMediator>` owned elsewhere would be one possible way to handle this design, but there are several other problems in your implementation. (For example, `SyncMediator::add` takes a `Switcher` by value, which could refer to a different `SyncMediator` altogether; the API doesn't prevent a `SyncMediator` from owning a `Switcher` beloning to a different `SyncMediator`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed explanation of **the Mediator pattern in Rust** here: https://github.com/fadeevab/mediator-pattern-rust

In short, there are two approaches:

1. **Cross-Referencing with `Rc<RefCell<..>>`**. It's kind of mimicking a classic OOP with Rust.

   In your case, you'd have

   ```rust
   let mediator = Rc::new(RefCell::new(SyncMediator { .. }));
   let switcher1 = Rc::new(Switcher { mediator: mediator.clone(), .. });

   {
       let mut mediator = mediator.borrow_mut();
       mediator.add(switcher1.clone());
       mediator.add(switcher2.clone());
   }
   ```

   passing the references across the objects. I call it a "naive" approach.
2. **Top-down ownership** approach, which adapts a classic Mediator definition to what could be safely and idiomatically done in the Rust language.
   You should create a mediator, switchers, then you should move ownership of switchers to the mediator, and overall do like this:

   ```rust
   let mut mediator = SyncMediator { .. };
   let switcher1 = Switcher { name: "switcher1", .. };

   mediator.add(switcher1);
   mediator.add(switcher2);

   // Then, work with the mediator at the top level.
   mediator.set_state("switcher1", true);
   ```

   where the switcher receives the mediator object as a function parameter:

   ```rust
   impl Switcher {
       fn set_state(&mut self, value: bool, mediator: &mut SyncMediator) {
           self.state = value;
           mediator.sync();
       }
   }
   ```

P.S.: The following image illustrates an example of interactions between visual components, where the Dialog is the Mediator.

[image: Top-Down Ownership approach]